# Detecting PWA Installation

Tags: javascript, installation, dom-events, progressive-web-apps

I'm following the following example to make my first, very simple PWA :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/making-a-simple-pwa-under-5-minutes/

Is there a way to make the installation more attractive by detecting events? For instance:

1. User accesses a website (for instance a travel website's homepage) and clicks an "Install Our Mobile App" button.
2. When the user clicks that button, the travel homepage stays the same but a prompt occurs in the browser to add to the home screen on their mobile device.
3. Once this is done, the homepage detects this event has been completed and redirects to a page that says, "Thank you for installing our mobile app. Find the icon on your phone and click it to open it. You may close this web page or click here to go to our homepage."

See, currently what happens in the Geeks for Geeks example is that I see the same exact content as the PWA, but get an option to click to add to the mobile device home screen.

Comment: Does this help? https://web.dev/customize-install/

Comment: Yes it does. That's the solution. I just implemented a sample of it and it works great. What that doc doesn't tell you, however, is that you need to remember to keep your code that registers the service worker on page load event that was in the Geeks for Geeks example.